# Sankey Diagram Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, local-variables, sankey-diagram

I am doing some twitter analysis and would like to use the [pySankey](https://github.com/anazalea/pySankey) package to visualise my results. But when I try to use this package, I get the following error that originates from the package itself. Does anyone know how to fix this? I am using python 3

UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      6 
      7 sankey.sankey(df['State'], df['Location'], aspect=20, colorDict=colorDict,
----> 8               fontsize=1, figure_name="Twitter Sentiment-Topic Per State"
      9              )

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pySankey/sankey.py in sankey(left, right, leftWeight, rightWeight, colorDict, leftLabels, rightLabels, aspect, rightColor, fontsize, figure_name, closePlot)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'topEdge' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give a try to https://github.com/ricklupton/ipysankeywidget

p.s. it provides interactive jupyter functionality, etc.[image]

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ricklupton/ipysankeywidget/blob/master/examples/More%20examples.ipynb#Styling

Another nice sankey python lib is: https://github.com/ricklupton/floweaver